# Importing a modular Javascript file using $.getScript()

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm using this script to import a couple of files when a user clicks on a button:

```
<script>
  async function loadScript(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.getScript(url, resolve);
    });
  }

  const pageType = $('.model-report-wrapper').data('page-type');

  let reportingScriptIsntLoaded = true;

  $('#model-report-button').popover();

  $('.model-report-wrapper').on('click', async function () {
    try {
      $('#model-report-button span').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></i> Loading...');

      if(reportingScriptIsntLoaded){
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const link = document.createElement('link');
          link.rel = 'stylesheet';
          link.href = '/css/firebase/report.css';
          link.type = 'text/css';
          link.onload = resolve;
          link.onerror = reject;
          document.head.appendChild(link);
        });

        await loadScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js');
        await loadScript('/js/firebase/report.js');

        reportingScriptIsntLoaded = false;
      }

      $('#model-report-button').popover('show');
      $('#model-report-button span').text('Report Content Issue');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading scripts:', error);
    }
  });
</script>
```

And the `report.js` is basically a file that has a functions with the executions in it:

```
function initializeReporting() {
    ...
}

initializeReporting()
```

This works as it should, but the problem is I need to use a modular version for `report.js` and I'm confused on how `$.getScript()` needs to be used to import it. `report.js` uses `firebase` heavily so I need to upgrade it so that I can start using firebase modules in it. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: I really wouldn’t reinvent [the wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)

Comment: @Quentin How would I use `import` in this case? I'm not very familiar with modular writing.

Comment: @Quentin Nvm I figured it out, thanks for pointing it out.